Can we increase AWS API Gateway integration timeout for Edge API?
As per AWS documentation you can increase API integration timeout only for Regional APIs and private APIs after quota request (Default value is 29 seconds).
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html
However, I was able to request more quota and increase timeout for an Edge API through AWS Console (no error happened).
Now I'm wondering if it works for Edge APIs or not. This API Gateway has integration proxy with Lambda.



By the documentation

If your API clients are geographically dispersed, consider using an
edge-optimized API endpoint in API Gateway. This type of endpoint acts
as a Regional endpoint with an AWS managed CloudFront web distribution
to improve client connection time.

So what apply to a regional still apply to edge-optimized. in brivety those are deployment options for api gateway so your timeout should work as expected  but if you need to test it you can simulate the timeout by :

modifying the Lambda function to intentionally take longer than the configured timeout, a time.sleep() statement (in Python) or equivalent.

Invoke the API Gateway endpoint using a tool like curl :
curl -X GET https://your-api-id.execute-api.your-region.amazonaws.com/stage/resource



I tested a lambda function with time.sleep(40) and API Gateway integration timeout with 50 seconds for both Edge and Regional API. It didn't work for the Edge (Cloudfront 503 error service unavailable) but worked for the Regional API. Lambda response retrieved properly for Regional in about 40s and Cloudfront error in about 90s for Edge. Tested with curl command as suggested.

Cloud front has also a response tiemout by default it's 30, so cf:30 > AGW: 50 > lambda:sleep(40). but you will get a 504 not an 503.?!

Another point is 90s > 89s that's is showed in your original post, can you check this settings via get-integration ? just to be sure that's 50s configured in your tests.

yes, 50s is configured on my tests. The 89s was only an example that I could configure more than 29s (default value).

Regarding CloudFront error, both errors are happening for the same request: 504 and 503.

Here is an example/screenshot of both requests I executed right now: https://ibb.co/5RjwzQL

Also, this is the Cloudfront managed by AWS when you use Edge API so I can't edit any config on that.
